# Mongoose select subdocuments with random sort (shuffle subdocuments)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have nodejs/mongodb and mongoose setup. Everything is the last version.

This is my structure:

```
   documents: [{
         _id: ObjectId
         subdocuments: [ObjectId, ObjectId, ObjectId, ObjectId]
   }]
```

or one more possible case for me:

```
   documents: [{
         _id: ObjectId
         subdocuments: [{
              _id: ObjectId
         }]
   }]
```

I need to select document using `db.documents.findOne({ _id: id })` subdocuments order subdocuments ObjectIds and sort them by random (just shuffle nested array by doing this on database side).

As far as I know, I can use `$sample` aggregation but... can I apply this with mongoose when I select subdocuments?

I'm very new in NoSQL. So this is possibly not a popular case but I need this. Probably I can do this on NodeJS side instead but looking for mongodb/mongoose solution first.

Comment: $sample would give you 'n' num of documents where 'n' is specified i.e; there could be a chance of duplicate documents in o/p, What exactly do you mean by random sort ? Do you want couple of documents out of collection ? Since you're using node.js your well built aggregation query with .aggregate() should run normal though you use mongoose !! Also when you mean subdocuments do you want actual docs associated with ObjectId's in subdocuments array ?

Comment: Please avoid phrases like " the last version". The "last" changes over time. Not critical in this particular question but it's better to be specific and name exact versions you are using. Although it is possible to use aggregation's $sample with mongoose it doesn't shuffle the array, it samples it - please read the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#behavior. It will be much simpler and computationally cheaper to shuffle the array in javascript.